# Is there a way to run Bamboo tests simultaneously?

Tags: java, junit, selenium, bamboo

Currently, I have two selenium-junit tests configured to run on bamboo about the same time. One test runs on MachineA (selenium etc. installed) and the other on MachineB (selenium etc. installed). When kicked off, bamboo builds the one on machineA and enqueues the one on machineB. My question is why cant bamboo handle multithreading? or is there a way around this problem

Comment: Do you have the requirement that script 1 must run on machine A and script 2 on machine B? If not, i would configure a single script and handle multi-threading on selinium side.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Bamboo v3, but it looks like you should be able to do it from that version onwards, as it supports a comprehensive "pipeline build system".

From what I read [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Working+with+Projects,+Stages,+Plans+and+Jobs), you would define your two Selenium tests as Jobs that are to be executed in the same Stage. As long as you have sufficient agents available, it should execute them in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

As Millhouse suggests you should use Bamboo 3 and configure your selenium-junit tests as Jobs in the same Stage of a Plan. Jobs in a given stage are executed in parallel given there's enough available agents.